# Unityで作成したプロジェクトをiPhoneで実行する際にlinker errorが発生します．

Tags: ios, xcode, unity3d, xcode7, ios9

Unityでgoogle cardboardを使ったコンテンツを作ろうとしています．
そのためにまずgoogleから提供されているsampleをiphoneで起動しようとしてみたところ，errorが発生しました．
手順は
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started-ios?hl=ja
に書いてある通りに行いました．
ただ「Xcodeでプロジェクトを展開する」の8.で行うLocalizable.stringsを取り込む工程のみ，「[your Unity project]/Assets/Plugins/iOS」内にLocalizable.stringsというファイルがなかったので行えませんでした．

errorは

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      ___75-[GTMSessionFetcher URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:]_block_invoke651 in libvrunity.a(GTMSessionFetcher.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

上記の通りです．
このerrorをどう回避したらいいのか全くわかりません．
Localizable.stringsを取り込んでいないから起こるのでしょうか？
それとも何か設定の問題なのでしょうか？
バージョンは
xcode : 7.2.1
iOS : 9.2
Unity : 5.3.1  です．

どうかよろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 1):

まず手順を守れていないなら、守ってから確認したほうがよいと思います。

> http://starzero.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/02/21/170902

Localizable.stringsの生成については上記を参考にしてください。

あとエラー文ですが、securityのフレームワークが設定されてないのでは？と思います。

> _SecTrustEvaluate

この部分から推察してます。

**Security.framework**を追加して試してみてください。